Do IDP Metadata Elements Follow the Same Naming Conventions Across Different IDPs?
I'm currently working on a project that involves integrating multiple Identity Providers (IDPs) using SAML 2.0. I understand that SAML 2.0 provides a standard for exchanging authentication and authorization data, but I'm unsure about the consistency of metadata elements across different IDPs.
Specifically:

Are the element names in IDP metadata consistent across various IDPs?

Are there any common variations or extensions that different IDPs might use?

How strictly do IDPs adhere to the SAML 2.0 standard for metadata?


Here's a basic example of IDP metadata structure I'm working with:
<EntityDescriptor entityID="https://idp.example.com">
  <IDPSSODescriptor>
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <KeyInfo>...</KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://idp.example.com/SSO/Redirect"/>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
  </IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>


SAML metadata is a standard, so if the IDP follows it (which they do, in my experience), it will be consistent.
However, some IDPs provide a lot of metadata, whereas others provide the bare minimum.
